# Golang error UpdateAllTokens and Generate All tokens are not declared by package?

Tags: go

while developing JWT in golang I am getting errors updatealltoken and generatealltoken - "these two not declared by package", every other models has no problem except than those 3 , what is the problem?

am i missing something please help?   if you please help me i will be very thankful to you ,because i just can't seems to figure out the issue no other issue than that.

```
 package controllers
    
    import (
        "context"
        "fmt"
        "log"
        "net/http"
        "time"
    
        "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
        "github.com/go-playground/validator/v10"
        "github.com/jwt/database"
        "github.com/jwt/models"
        helper "github.com/jwt/models"
        "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson"
        "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson/primitive"
        "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo"
        "golang.org/x/crypto/bcrypt"
    )
    
    var userCollection *mongo.Collection = database.OpenCollection(database.Client, "user")
    var validate = validator.New()
    
    //HashPassword is used to encrypt the password before it is stored in the DB
    func HashPassword(password string) string {
        bytes, err := bcrypt.GenerateFromPassword([]byte(password), 14)
        if err != nil {
            log.Panic(err)
        }
        return string(bytes)
    
    }
    
    //VerifyPassword checks the input password while verifying it with the passward in the DB.
    func VerifyPassword(userPassword string, providedPassword string) (bool, string) {
        err := bcrypt.CompareHashAndPassword([]byte(providedPassword), []byte(userPassword))
        check := true
        msg := ""
        if err != nil {
            msg = fmt.Sprintf("login or password is incorrect")
            check = false
        }
        return check, msg
    }
    
    ////CreateUser is the api used to get a single user
    func SignUp() gin.HandlerFunc {
        return func(c *gin.Context) {
            var ctx, cancel = context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 100*time.Second)
            var user models.User
            if err := c.BindJSON(&user); err != nil {
                c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{"error": err.Error()})
                return
            }
            validationErr := validate.Struct(user)
            if validationErr != nil {
                c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{"error": validationErr.Error()})
                return
            }
            count, err := userCollection.CountDocuments(ctx, bson.M{"email": user.Email})
            defer cancel()
            if err != nil {
                log.Panic(err)
                c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{"error": "error occured chacking with email"})
                return
            }
            password := HashPassword(*user.Password)
            user.Password = &password
            count, err = userCollection.CountDocuments(ctx, bson.M{"phone": user.Phone})
            defer cancel()
            if err != nil {
                log.Panic(err)
                c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{"error": "error occured with the checking for the phone number"})
                return
            }
            if count > 0 {
                c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{"error": "this email or phone number already exist"})
                return
            }
            user.Created_at, _ = time.Parse(time.RFC3339, time.Now().Format(time.RFC3339))
            user.Updated_at, _ = time.Parse(time.RFC3339, time.Now().Format(time.RFC3339))
            user.ID = primitive.NewObjectID()
            user.User_id = user.ID.Hex()
            token, refreshToken, _ := helper.GenerateAllTokens(*user.Email, *user.First_name, *user.Last_name, user.User_id)
            user.Token = &token
            user.Refresh_token = &refreshToken
            resultInsertionNumber, insertErr := userCollection.InsertOne(ctx, user)
            if insertErr != nil {
                msg := fmt.Sprintf("User iem was not created")
                c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{"error": msg})
                return
            }
            defer cancel()
            c.JSON(http.StatusOK, resultInsertionNumber)
        }
    
    }
    
    //Login is the api used to tget a single user
    func Login() gin.HandlerFunc {
        return func(c *gin.Context) {
            var ctx, cancel = context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 100*time.Second)
            var user models.User
            var foundUser models.User
    
            if err := c.BindJSON(&user); err != nil {
                c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{"error": err.Error()})
                return
            }
    
            err := userCollection.FindOne(ctx, bson.M{"email": user.Email}).Decode(&foundUser)
            defer cancel()
            if err != nil {
                c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{"error": "login or passowrd is incorrect"})
                return
            }
    
            passwordIsValid, msg := VerifyPassword(*user.Password, *foundUser.Password)
            defer cancel()
            if passwordIsValid != true {
                c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{"error": msg})
                return
            }
    
            token, refreshToken, _ := helper.GenerateAllTokens(*foundUser.Email, *foundUser.First_name, *foundUser.Last_name, foundUser.User_id)
    
            helper.UpdateAllTokens(token, refreshToken, foundUser.User_id)
    
            c.JSON(http.StatusOK, foundUser)
    
        }
    }
```

Comment: what packages are these `github.com/jwt/database` and `github.com/jwt/models` I can't seem to find those

Comment: When you get an error, please include it verbatim

Comment: These are my own packages splitting into clusters m models has the model user model cluster etc